# Can't install wifi driver in 12.04

Tags: wireless, atheros, ath9k

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 3521 with a Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter inside. After an update the WiFi broke and I cannot seem to fix it. I tried to follow the steps from [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2103062) thread where somebody has a similar problem to build the driver, but on *make* it gives me an error about redefinition of "kmalloc_array" even after `make clean` (I tried to build it previously in fact). The device is not hardware blocked, `rfkill list` outputs:

```
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

However, `lshw -C network` displays this as a result for the wifi adapter.

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:c0500000-c057ffff memory:afb00000-afb0ffff
```

and there is no driver=ath9k or whatever it must be.

Edit: `lsmod |grep mac80211` gives the following result:

```
mac80211       557654 1 ath9k
cfg80211       219204 3 ath9k,mac80211,ath
compat          20099 9 ath9k,mac80211,ath9k_common,ath9k_hw,cfg80211,rfcomm,bnep,btusb,bluetooth
```

How can I fix this?

Edit2: *uname -r* outputs

```
3.2.0-56-generic
```

*lspci -nn |grep 0280* outputs

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your kernel version from the terminal command: uname -r  Do you have the same device? lspci -nn | grep 0280

Comment: I faced same issue when I updated my kernel to 3.10.25. (Wireless was working fine with last kernel: 3.2). `lcpci -nn | grep 0280` returned `01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)`

Answer (score 0):

Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.8-precise-generic
```

Detach the ethernet, reboot and let us hear your report.

Comment: I faced same issue when updated my linux kernel from 3.2.0-32 to 3.10.25. `lcpci -nn | grep 0280` returned `01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)`. And installing linux-backports-modules-cw-3.10-precise-generic and the version you mentioned above and rebooting did not help.

Comment: Also, now if while booting Ubuntu I use version 3.2.0-32, even then the wireless doesn't work. Wireless was working fine with 3.2.0-32 till I installed 3.10.25. `iwconfig` btw returns `lo        no wireless extensions.

virbr0    no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
`

Comment: Same problem is reported here too: http://askubuntu.com/questions/395410/drivers-for-atheros-qca9565-ar9565-wireless-cardh

Comment: @baltusaj- I will be happy to help if you start your own new question.